# Organizing web services for mobile applications

Tags: php, actionscript-3, flex4

**Background**

I've written an internal use Playbook application for my company where users may login and gather certain sets of information from our database. However, not all users request the same information.

The app is written in the Adobe AIR framework as front-end and I use PHP/MSSQL as the back-end.

So far I've organized the PHP scripts in the following hierarchy on our internal webserver:

```
// Contains class whose constructor connects to our database
// and every method is a seperate query
./MyApp/liveScripts/service/Connection.php

// These are example php files that take POST inputs and executes the query
./MyApp/liveScripts/service/getDataX.php
./MyApp/liveScripts/service/getDataY.php
./MyApp/liveScripts/service/getDataZ.php
```

Each query returns data in XML format to be read by my app and then displayed.

**Problem**

At first I only had a few special queries, but now I'm facing around 40+ unique queries and the connection class is bloating with lots of unique methods.

In addition I find myself creating a lot of separate php files doing these queries and it feels very inefficient. Here is what 90% of my php files look like:

```
<?php

include("Connection.php");

$userid = $_POST['userid'];
$fooid = $_POST['fooid'];
$barid= $_POST['barid'];
$service = new Connection();

echo $service->getDataX($userid, $fooid, $barid);

?>
```

**Question**

My question is, from your experience what is the best way to organize PHP scripts when there are lots of unique queries to handle? Is having a Connection class that stores each separate query as a separate method and having a unique PHP file for each method a viable solution?

I've tried Googling other solutions and hierarchies but haven't come across anything yet.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try creating your queries dynamically by passing in a string of variables to a new method that returns the result. I've personally never used PHP/MSSQL for a PlayBook application but that's where I would start looking.